# layer configuration file unparsed line while creating Yocto build

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I have this layer configuration file in poky/meta-test/conf directory

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb"
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend 
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bb 
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bbappend ” 
BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += “test” 
BBFILE_PATTERN_test = “^${LAYERDIR}/” 
BBFILE_PRIORITY_test = “13” 
LAYERVERSION_test = “13”
```

And when I do

```
source oe-init-build-env build
bitbake core-image-minimal //error at this
```

error

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/ubuntu/Desktop/embedded_Emdevor/my/my/poky/meta-test/conf/layer.conf:5: unparsed line: '${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend \
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bb \
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bbappend ”
```